# Same container width

Tags: css

So, I have these two images. The HTML structure is like this:

```
<div class="buttonContainer">
    <div class="innerButton">
        <img src="...">
        <p> Some text </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

But as you can see, both containers have different heights (because of the length of the `p` content. I'm not a very  experienced at CSS, so any help is welcome.

[image]

Comment: you can define min-height button-container

Comment: maybe so - http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/7v2f9ztu/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.innerButton{
  min-height: /*set your height*/;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

1. Set **height attribute** to the `<p>` containing your text. But if the text is too long, it will overflow out of the `<p>`
2. **Truncate your text**: You can truncate your text using the following code.

`<p id="greetings">
  Hello universe!
</p>`

**CSS**

```
#greetings
{ width: 100px;
 white-space: nowrap;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Then text will become
`Hello univ…`

Answer (score 1):

A good question and one I encounter a lot.

Firstly you have two options that work well. Go the pure CSS route or use some jQuery. The latter being easier to implement and to be honest, overheads are not too bad either.

The reason I've not gone for using min-height is I am assuming you might want this working responsively where min-heights can be an annoyance. This method means you never need to specify heights explicitly which in my opinion is better.

### **1. Pure CSS (using display table)**

```
.buttonGrouping.css{
    display: table;
    border-spacing: 20px;
}

.css .buttonContainer{
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 0 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

HTML for CSS tables

```
<!--Example using CSS-->
<div class="buttonGrouping css">

    <div class="buttonContainer">
            <div class="innerButton">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
                    <p> Some text </p>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="buttonContainer">
            <div class="innerButton">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
                    <p> Some text </p>
                    <p> Another para </p>
            </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

### **2. jQuery (using matchHeight.js)**

Note you I've included the matchHeight plugin in the live example at the bottom. The plugin can be [found here](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height).

CSS:

```
.buttonGrouping.jquery{
    clear: both;
}

.jquery .buttonContainer{
    float: left;    
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0 20px;
}
```

And initialize the script on the element...

```
$(".jquery .buttonContainer").matchHeight();
```

Please note the `.jquery` in the script is just a class i added to each example to separate them out.

[Live examples](http://codepen.io/vdecree/pen/bdaGXK)